# How to store chrome identity api response in vuejs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm passing the response from chrome identity api to the tab that will run my vue powered chrome extension. I need to store this information inside my vue instance tu use it inside a component. I've tried to assign the info to a variable using `this.username` but it will result in undefined in console. What's wrong with the code and what's the best way to accomplish this?

component code

```
<script>
import { EventBus } from '../../event-bus';

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      socket: null,
      isRegistered: false,
      isConnected: false,
      username: null,
      message: '',
    }
  },
  created() {

  },
  mounted() {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender){
      console.log(request);
      this.username = request.name;
      this.isRegistered = true;
    });
    EventBus.$emit('open-connection')
// the variable is undefined and also the open-connection event are not emitted?
    console.log(this.username)
    EventBus.$on('connected', (socket) => {
      console.log(socket)
      this.socket = socket;
      this.isConnected = true;
      console.log(this.socket.id)
    })
  },
  methods: {
// I was using this method but the function isn't called inside mounted, result in an error :(
    connect(){
      //if( this.isRegistered === false){
        //this.username = this.username;
        //this.isRegistered = true;
        //EventBus.$emit('open-connection')
        //return this.username;
     // }
    }
    // methods here 
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

The response from identity api (I will omit the fields value for privacy):

```
{
  "id": "100xxxxxx",
  "name": "xxx",
  "given_name": "xxxx",
  "family_name": "xxxx",
  "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/xxxxx.jpg",
  "locale": "xx"
}
```

NB: the response object is not accessible in this way `key.val`

**EDIT**

After some debug I've finally found a solution. The response information retrived by the api isn't really an object but a JSON. I've used the `JSON.parse()` function to make it an object and now I'm able to access to the fields using `key.value` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use the `chrome.storage` to set/get the data rather than rely on the components state.

Otherwise can you share what the `console.log(request)` is giving you and what the background script looks like?

Comment: If I log I can see an object, but I can't access the properties of it using in vue fore example `request.name`

Comment: Can you share the object you get?

Comment: I think I see a problem. The addEventListener uses a callback to set the username. This can be seen if you console log the `this.username` right after your assignment. You can try emoving your eventBus logic inside the callback (function(request, sender) so you know the username is set by the time the EventBus.$emit is called.

Comment: I have already modified the code to try finding a solution, but it seems that the response object from the identity api isn't accessible in any way. I'm trying to log the single fields inside the background script of the extension but this result in `undefined` in console